# If $ a,b,c \gt 0 $ and $ \frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{b+1} + \frac{1}{c+1} = 1 $ Prove $ abc \geq 8 $

Tags: inequality

If $ a,b,c \gt 0 $  and  $ \frac{1}{a+1} + \frac{1}{b+1} + \frac{1}{c+1} = 1 $

Prove $ abc \geq 8 $

I have tried AM-GM and substituting the 1, without results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simplifies to $$a+b+c+2=abc$$
$$⇒\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{2}{abc}=1$$
Applying AM-GM inequality we get
$$\frac{1}{4}=\frac{\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ac}+\frac{2}{abc}}{4}≥(\frac{2}{a^3b^3c^3})^\frac{1}{4}$$
Riasing both sides to the power of 4 we get
$$\frac{1}{256}≥(\frac{2}{a^3b^3c^3})$$

$$⇒abc≥8$$

Comment: wow you're so smart, thanks

Comment: I got to $a + b + c + 2 = abc$ but was stuck. Dividing through by $abc$ and applying AM-GM with 4 terms was neat. Thanks for showing me!

Comment: @Sam We cban prove without dividing by abc. $$\frac{abc}{4}=\frac{a+b+c+2}{4}≥(2abc)^\frac{1}{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$x = \frac{1}{a+1}, \quad y = \frac{1}{b+1},  \quad z = \frac{1}{c+1},$$
then $x+y+z=1$ and
$$a = \frac{1-x}{x} = \frac{y+z}{x}.$$
The inequality become
$$\frac{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}{xyz} \geqslant 8.$$
Which is true because
$$\frac{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}{xyz} \geqslant \frac{2\sqrt{xy} \cdot 2\sqrt{yz} \cdot 2\sqrt{zx}}{xyz} = 8.$$
The proof is completed.